# Comparing Characters in java

Tags: java, character

I have an array

```
char[] A = {'a','c','e','b','d'};
```

I want to arrange the array in ascending order i.e

```
A ={'a','b','c','d','e'};
```

How it can be done in java as simple `>` operator will not give me correct answer.
code:

```
for(int i=A.length-1; i>=1;i--)
{
    if(A[i]<A[i-1])
    {
        char a =A[i];
        A[i] = A[i-1];
        A[i-1] = a;                          
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide your attempt with code. We won't solve your exercise/homework.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i have simple loop through them and used `>` operator

Comment: Don't describe your code. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25830263/edit) your question and provide that code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm afraid somebody probably will do this homework - the odds are against your prediction.

Comment: Now we need more code. What's `word` variable, how is declared, initialized and probably filled?

Comment: Shouldn't it be char[] A = {'a','c','e','b','d'}; ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  you are only making one pass through the array.  That is not sufficient.

If you don't understand what I mean, try "hand executing" the code with an input array that has the letters in the *reverse order* to what is required.

- Does one pass through the entire array give you a properly sorted array?
- What did it actually do?
- So what do you need to do now .... ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you are trying to do is the beginning of what we call `Bubblesort`. You have made a single pass through the list of characters and only swapped some of them. You effectively have to repeat the process until no swaps occur.

More information about `Bubblesort`ing can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). In particular there is pseudo code that outlines the concept:

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
    n = length(A)
    repeat     
        swapped = false
        for i = 1 to  n-1 inclusive do
            /* if this pair is out of order */
            if A[i-1] > A[i] then
                /* swap them and remember something changed */
                swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
                swapped = true
            end if
        end for
    until not swapped
end procedure
```